# column of table cells text to links

Tags: php, mysql, database, string

I'm creating a table dynamically from a mysql database that gets fields name, email, city. The email column has emails that I'd like to have as "mailto:" links. Currently they display the email without the hyperlink. There's a 'filter' form on the page as well that when submitted will display only results that correspond with a name specified in the form textbox by the user.

I'm very novice at creating anything dynamic. What's the easiest way to display the email column as hyperlinks? I was thinking about using javascript to do a getElementByID loop for the second td of every tr and amend a "mailto:" the beginning using string manipulation. Maybe this is more practically done in PHP instead?

edit:
I realized the obvious solution to my question. I simply concatenated the a href mailto: before the echo of the php command that gets my email field from the sql db and displays it in the table.

Answer (score 1):

This is, indeed, more practically done in PHP. You can use something like the following, assuming that `$result` contains the result of a MySQL `SELECT` statement which fetches the users.

```php
while ($u = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Output other data
    // ...

    echo '<a href="mailto:' . $u['email'] . '">' . $u['email'] . '</a>';

    // ...
}
```

If you're still using `mysql` instead of `mysqli` (which you shouldn't really be doing), then replace

```
while ($u = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

with

```
while ($u = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I realized this would be the most elegant solution after a little bit of pondering of my own as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
$db = new PDO(//your dsn, host and password); 
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT name,email from users'); 
$query->execute(); while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
 echo '<a href="mailto:"'.$row['email'].'">'.$row['name'].'</a>'; 
}
```